# Is libc++ providing hash specialization for too many basic_string_view's?

Tags: c++, hash, c++17, libc++, string-view

Per [[string.view.synop]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/string.view.synop):

> ```
> // ...
>
> // [string.view.hash], hash support
> template<class T> struct hash;
> template<> struct hash<string_view>;
> template<> struct hash<u16string_view>;
> template<> struct hash<u32string_view>;
> template<> struct hash<wstring_view>;
>
> // ...
> ```

Only for the four "common" `basic_string_view`s are specializations of `hash` enabled.  The other `basic_string_view`s have their `hash`es disabled.

Per [[unord.hash]/2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/unord.hash#2):

> [...] For any type `Key` for which neither the library nor the user
>   provides an explicit or partial specialization of the class template
>   `hash`, `hash<Key>` is disabled.

Per [[unord.hash]/4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/unord.hash#4):

> If `H` is a disabled specialization of `hash`, these values are false:
>   `is_­default_­constructible_­v<H>`, `is_­copy_­constructible_­v<H>`,
>   `is_­move_­constructible_­v<H>`, `is_­copy_­assignable_­v<H>`, and
>   `is_­move_­assignable_­v<H>`. Disabled specializations of `hash` are
>   not function object types. [ *Note:* This means that the
>   specialization of hash exists, but any attempts to use it as a `Hash`
>   will be ill-formed. — *end note* ]

Therefore, the following Minimal Reproducible Example should not compile because it attempts to default construct a disabled specialization of `hash`:

```
#include <string_view>

// trait is a char trait distinct from std::char_traits<char>
struct trait :std::char_traits<char> {
    using char_traits<char>::char_traits;
};

int main()
{
    [[maybe_unused]] std::hash<std::basic_string_view<char, trait>> x;
}
```

However, this compiles [fine](https://wandbox.org/permlink/9AStewINh9CngXkt) on Clang 8.0.0.  Digging down the source of libc++, we [see](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/libcxx/blob/master/include/string_view#L778-L787):

```
// [string.view.hash]
template<class _CharT, class _Traits>
struct _LIBCPP_TEMPLATE_VIS hash<basic_string_view<_CharT, _Traits> >
    : public unary_function<basic_string_view<_CharT, _Traits>, size_t>
{
    _LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY
    size_t operator()(const basic_string_view<_CharT, _Traits> __val) const _NOEXCEPT {
        return __do_string_hash(__val.data(), __val.data() + __val.size());
    }
};
```

So libc++ actually enables `hash` for all `basic_string_view`s.

Therefore, I conclude that this is a bug in libc++.  Is my analysis correct?

Comment: The place to report bugs for libc++ is https://bugs.llvm.org

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You appear to be correct. Libc++ correctly disables your hash for `std::basic_string`, but not for `std::basic_string_view`.

Later: Fixed for LLVM 9.0

Comment: Does it?  The same code compiles [fine](https://wandbox.org/permlink/rIeX0MjrNgBZOu5Y) when I change `basic_string_view` to `basic_string`.

Comment: It does not for me using ToT clang and libc++ - and if you change your Wandbox settings to "Clang HEAD", it fails to compile.

Comment: Thanks for the information! I definitely should check the latest version before declaring a bug.